# Mathematical Modelling of AC Servomotor

Tags: motor, control, control-system, modeling, electrical

i want to model an AC Servomotor where i assume that a dynamic load is attached to the shaft of AC Servomotor. the link of the paper that i have attached in the start of this post has ac servomotor model running without load thats why in equation 5 TL(s) (the load torque)=0 . Now i want to include TL(s) in the model which means that a load is connected to the shaft of the motor. in order to include TL(s) into the system i need to know the formulla of the TL(s) becouse i can not simply include TL(s) in the equation else i will not be able to get the final transfer function ( Theta(s)/E(s) ). So i am thinking to put in the components of the TL(s) into the equation such as T=KI or T=J(inertia) * a(accelaration).

So May someone plz help me that what can be the correct equation of TL(s) in this case so i can subtitute in? or/and how can i include the load torque (TL(s)) into the motor model.[enter link description here](https://ijeir.org/administrator/components/com_jresearch/files/publications/IJEIR-1470_Final.pdf)

Comment: k/V, mass, radius, Vmax, T max, load, Imax or DCR,  excitation current, friction?

Comment: So do you intend to introduce a time-varying load rather than an inertial or frictional load?

Comment: Yes Sir, i want to introduce a time-varying load. @Chu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Torque is the rate of change of angular momentum, \$\small L=J\omega\$, where \$\small J\$ is inertia and \$\omega\$ is angular velocity, thus: $$T=\frac{d}{dt}(J\omega)$$

Normally, inertia is constant, which means: \$T=J\frac{d\omega}{dt}=J\alpha\$, but if inertia is also a function of time, we need to use the product rule, hence:
$$T=J\frac{d\omega}{dt}+ \omega\frac{dJ}{dt}$$
A block diagram can be generated from this equation.

If inertia is a function of angular position as in, for example, a multi-jointed robot arm or four-bar mechanism, the analysis is a lot easier.

Comment: how about if i do it like the following: Equation (2) in the attachment defines motor torque in terms of inertia (J), friction (B), and load torque (TL).
Replace the (TL) term with its component terms (load inertia (JL) and load friction (BL)), and carry them thru the balance of the calculations.

Comment: How, exactly, does the load inertia change? What's the equation?

Comment: torque=J*Accelaration          so when load torque changes its inertia will change too.

Comment: Motor developed torque is the input, and acceleration is the output. If the inertia increases, the acceleration decreases, etc...